# <firebase-query> error: "Cannot create property '$key' on string..."

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am trying to use the `polymerfire/firebase-query` to load my data stored in Firebase using the [Vaadin Expense Manager Demo](https://github.com/vaadin/expense-manager-demo). Specifically, I am trying to replace the `<vaadin-pouchdb>` element with a combination of `<firebase-query>` and `</app-indexeddb-mirror>`.

https://github.com/vaadin/expense-manager-demo/blob/master/src/overview-page.html

```
<firebase-query
  id="query"
  log
  app-name="my-firebase"
  path="[[user.uid]]"
  data="{{expenses}}">
</firebase-query>
```

When I try to load the page, I expect to see my grid populate with test data; but instead, I get the following errors.

console.log

> firebase.js:284 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '$key' on string 'foo'
>
> firebase.js:284 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '$key' on string 'new'
>
> firebase.js:284 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '$key' on number '123'

The value of `{{expenses}}` I expect to be delivered to the app via `<firebase-query>` is the following:

```
expenses = [
  {
    total    : 123   ,
    status   : 'new' ,
    merchant : 'foo' ,
  },
]
```

What could be creating this error? Why is there a property `'$key'`, trying to be created? Oh, wait. Could it be because there is no key associated with the expenses as they are stored in my Firebase?

Edit:

Here is what the data looks like in Firebase:

```
my-firebase
│
└──my-userid-abc-123
   ├── merchant: "foo"
   ├── status: "new"
   └── total: 123
```

Comment: Can you show what your actual data in the database looks like? Are you storing things with numeric keys? `firebase-query` is designed to work with string-keyed object data.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh: Yes. Your instincts were correct. I do not have keys on the stored data. *See above edits reflecting structure of stored data.* How can I populate my grid then? If I need to go back and store the data with keys, let me know. It sounds like that might be best from a data structure perspective to do this?

Comment: It looks like you probably want `firebase-document` which will just load the entire document at the path. I'd also strongly encourage structuring your data with e.g. `/users/my-userid-123` instead of putting the users directly at the root level. Then you could just do `<firebase-document path="/users/[[user.uid]]">` or to get all users `<firebase-query path="/users">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<firebase-query>` on locations where all of the children have primitive `(boolean, string, number)` values is not supported. Please consider nesting these values in objects.

Comment: What!?! Really!?! Thanks for the answer, but who designed this?